# Windows batch equivalent of bash script using conditional "IF statement"

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

I have an installer package that I want to script a silent install. The package has a version for both Linux and Windows. It requires the existence of two files; a bin (*nix) or exe (Win) and an additional digital certificate ssl file.

I wrote a bash script that checks for the existence of both files before proceeding with the installation on Linux.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
CFILE="/tmp/cert.ssl"
BFILE="/tmp/installer.bin"
SRV="192.168.1.2"
APORT="443"


    if [[ -e ${BFILE} && -e ${CFILE} ]] && echo "Both cert and bin files exist in /tmp"
then
    echo "Proceeding with installation!"
chmod 764 ${BFILE}  
${BFILE} -silent -server=${SRV} -cert=${CFILE} -agentport=${APORT} 
else
    echo "Installation aborted. Please ensure that the cert and bin file are located in /tmp"

fi
```

I am trying to write something similar in Windows Batch to run installer.exe using a nested If Exists. I am testing the script using "echo", but it doesn't appear to be handling the nested IF correctly. If I remove installer.exe, the ELSE condition works. If I remove cert.ssl it doesn't.

```
::=========================
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

IF EXIST "C:\temp\installer.exe" (
    IF EXIST "C:\temp\cert.ssl" (
        echo "Both cert and bin files exist in "C:\temp". Proceeding with the installation!"
        timeout /t 10 )
    ) ELSE (
        echo "Installation aborted. Please ensure that the cert and bin file are located in "C:\temp""
        timeout /t 10
    )

:END
```

Comment: Try this: http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: Is there a way to search for both files in the one IF statement or do I have no nest commands?

Comment: I guess I've never tried! :) I wouldn't recommend it though. IMO it would be better to test for each file separately so you can output a message (perhaps to a log file) stating which file is missing. I'm sure you could nest the IFs: `IF EXIST "\tmp\cert.ssl" (IF EXIST "\tmp\installer.bin" ([do stuff]))`", but I don't know if you can use any conditionals to condense that further.

Comment: I edited my original post adding what I have so far. It's not working quite right yet.

Comment: Odd. What you have works for me (if I change the paths to two text files on my machine).

Comment: If one of the files is missing you get the "Installation Aborted" message?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the ELSE condition, but rather the nested IF. I've revised the last paragraph in my post to better explain the scenario.

Comment: You have `IF condition DO [IF condition DO (stuff)] ELSE [other stuff]` Do both IFs work independently?

Comment: No, both files need to exist before proceeding to install. If one or both are missing, then the script should abort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you close the outer `if` statement?

```
IF EXIST "C:\temp\installer.exe" (
    IF EXIST "C:\temp\cert.ssl" (
        echo "Both cert and bin files exist in "C:\temp". Proceeding with the installation!"
        timeout /t 10
    ) ELSE (
        echo "Installation aborted. Please ensure that the cert and bin file are located in "C:\temp""
        timeout /t 10
    )
REM Closing outer if
)

:END
```

Personally, I would prefer to use `if not` instead:

```
IF NOT EXIST "C:\temp\installer.exe" (
    echo "Missing bin file"
    goto END
)

IF NOT EXIST "C:\temp\cert.ssl" (
    echo "Missing cert file"
    goto END
)

echo "Both cert and bin files exist in "C:\temp". Proceeding with the installation!"
timeout /t 10

:END
```